# java - concurrent updates to multiple objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new in Java concurrency, I have a class holding data (doubles in the sample code below) that should be accessed with a get (like a Map), but with data stored internally in a array for performance reasons.

This run in a multithreaded environment and this index must be updated sometimes.

```
public class ConcurrencySampleCode {

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    private Map<String, Integer> map = ...
    private double[] array = ...

    public Double get(String id) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            Integer i = map.get(id);
            if (i == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return array[i];
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        Map<String, Integer> tmpMap = updateMap(...);
        double[] tmpArray = updateArray(...);
        synchronized (lock) { // should be atomic
            map = tmpMap;
            array = tmpArray;
        }
    }

}
```

I am not sure whether this code is correct or not? Also, is the synchronized keyword needed in the get function ?

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Besides your code, there is a [ConcurrentMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) implementation.

Comment: Agreed, use ConcurrentMap. A ConcurrentHashMap for example would be thread safe and faster than what your doing here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Also [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: How should I use the ConcurrentMap ? As I have to update the map and the array atomically ?

Comment: Hmm, what's with all the concurrency questions today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, but you will need to use the [volatile](https://dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0) keyword on the map and the array to ensure all threads see the updated values immediately, and I'm not sure you want the lock to be static.

As an alternative you may want to check out the [java.util.concurrent.atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package. It has some handy thread-safe variable. For example you could move your map and array into their own class, then use the AtomicReference to store the object.

```
public class ConcurrencySampleCode {

    private AtomicReference<DoubleMap> atomicMap = new AtomicReference(new DoubleMap());

    //Inner class used to hold the map and array pair
    public class DoubleMap {
        private Map<String, Integer> map = ...
        private double[] array = ...
    }

    public Double get(String id) {
        DoubleMap map = atomicMap.get();
            ...
    }

    public void update() {
        Map<String, Integer> tmpMap = updateMap(...);
        double[] tmpArray = updateArray(...);
        DoubleMap newMap = new DoubleMap(tmpMap, tmpArray);
        atomicMap.set(newMap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on in concurrent programming, but for instance your `update()` method is faulty. In the current state multiple `Threads` can call `ConcurrencySampleCode.update()` and every each one of them will initiate both `update` calls inside the body before the synchronization kicks in. This means that after the round-robin turnover the last `Thread` with the update call will not have the changes from the previous `update` calls in the newly update map and array.

Long story, try to use and understand the [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: What I do not understand is how I mix a ConcurrentHashMap and the array, as they need to be updated atomically. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ogen The concurrent package is huge in Java. You can read their description and see if it fits your needs. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Comment: OK, I am reading the doc (especially Semaphore). However I can't see the relation between my sample code and the ConcurrentMap as the issue is the atomicity of the update of both the map and the array. Am I missing something